# Mastermind Game Java Swing, MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, icons, joptionpane, mouselistener

I am working on a Mastermind game for Java Object Oriented Programming and I have everything working except for one part of the code is

```
    if(uG[0].getIcon() == compGuess[0].getIcon() && uG[1].getIcon() == compGuess[1].getIcon() && uG[2].getIcon() == compGuess[2].getIcon() && uG[3].getIcon() == compGuess[3].getIcon())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f1, "You have guessed them all coorect!", "Mastermind: Test Your Mind", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            submit.setEnabled(false);

            compGuess[0].setEnabled(false);
            compGuess[1].setEnabled(false);
            compGuess[2].setEnabled(false);
            compGuess[3].setEnabled(false);

            compGuess[0].setVisible(true);
            compGuess[1].setVisible(true);
            compGuess[2].setVisible(true);
            compGuess[3].setVisible(true);

            uG[0].setEnabled(false);
            uG[1].setEnabled(false);
            uG[2].setEnabled(false);
            uG[3].setEnabled(false);

            System.exit(0);
        }
```

I am adding the full code because the above code ^^ show's where my problem is, but you can't figure out why it's not working the way it supposed to unless you look through the original full code. Yes, it may take a minute or two to read through, but it will help with the problem at hand. You can comment out the audio part to it and change the icon's. When its run, the computer guess will not display until you have guessed it all correct but that's the problem. Even if you have guessed it correctly, the game will not until you have guessed 10 times. I can't figure out why this is happening. Can anyone please help?

```
    import java.awt.*; 
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.swing.*; 
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream; 
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem; 
    import javax.sound.sampled.*;

    public class Mastermind extends JFrame
    {

    public static int found = 0;
    public static int guesses = 0;
    public final JTextField guess = new JTextField(20);
    public static JFormattedTextField nG = new JFormattedTextField();
public Mastermind()
{   

    final JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Mastermind: Can you win?");
    f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

    //runs a song/midi upon start of the game
    int replys = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f1, "Welcome to Mastermind! \n T he game to test your brain." +
                                                                      "\n\n\nWould you like to play?", "Mastermind: Test Your Brain!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(replys == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
        try
        {

            //AudioFormat audioFormat;
            //AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
            //SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

            File soundFile = new File("swfinal.mid");
                            AudioInputStream ai =      AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(ai);
            clip.start();
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {}
    }
    else
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //makes the panel to display the computer's guess
    final JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,4,5,5));
    f1.add(gamePanel);
    gamePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(5,5,5,5, Color.GREEN));
    gamePanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);   

    //the rules on how to play
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f1, "Welcome to Mastermind! \n The game to test your brain.", "Mastermind: Test Your Brain!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f1, "You have to guess what color is behind the circle the White cirlce" +
                                                     "\n This will display on the right side of the f1 for you." +
                                                     "\n Your guesses will display on the left side of the f1 for you." +
                                                     "\n You have 10 attempts at getting it correct" +
                                                     "after all 10 attmepts are done \nand you did not guess correctly, the game will end." +
                                                     "\n\n\n Now, good luck on Mastermind. May you have a very fun time!", "Mastermind Rules", J   OptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


    //makes the panel to display the heading
    final JPanel Gs = new JPanel();
    f1.add(Gs);
    Gs.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(5,5,5,5, Color.GREEN));
    Gs.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    //makes the panel where you control everything
    final JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    f1.add(p2);
    p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(5,5,5,5, Color.GREEN));
    p2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    final JLabel line = new JLabel("");
    p2.add(line);
    line.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

    //creates the submit button 
    final JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    p2.add(submit);

    //adds a text field to display the number of guesses
    final JFormattedTextField tf1 = new JFormattedTextField();
    p2.add(tf1);
    tf1.setColumns(2);
    tf1.setEditable(false);
    tf1.setForeground(Color.RED);
    tf1.setValue(new Integer(guesses));

    JLabel here = new JLabel("Take a guess: ");
            p2.add(here);
    here.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

    final JLabel master = new JLabel("MASTERMIND: TEST YOUR MIND!");
    master.setForeground(Color.green);
    Font newf = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 32);
    master.setFont(newf);
    Gs.add(master);

    //add and initializes the computers guess buttons
    //and its guesses
    final String[] colored = new String[4];
    colored[0] = "circle-red.png";
    colored[1] = "circle-blue.png";
    colored[2] = "circle-green.png";
    colored[3] = "circle-yellow.png";

    final JButton[] compGuess = new JButton[4];
    compGuess[0] = new JButton();
    compGuess[1] = new JButton();
    compGuess[2] = new JButton();
    compGuess[3] = new JButton();

    gamePanel.add(compGuess[0]);
    gamePanel.add(compGuess[1]);
    gamePanel.add(compGuess[2]);
    gamePanel.add(compGuess[3]);

    compGuess[0].setVisible(false);
    compGuess[1].setVisible(false);
    compGuess[2].setVisible(false);
    compGuess[3].setVisible(false);

    final String[] colored2 = new String[4];
    final int[] checkFilled = new int[4];
    for(int fill = 0; fill < 4; fill++)
    {
        checkFilled[fill] = 0;
    }
    int counter = 0;
    do
    {
        int Random = (int)(Math.random()*4);

        if(checkFilled[Random] == 0)
        {
            colored2[counter] = colored[Random];
            checkFilled[Random] = 1;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    while(counter < 4);

    final ImageIcon cell1 = new ImageIcon(colored2[0]);
    final ImageIcon cell2 = new ImageIcon(colored2[1]);
    final ImageIcon cell3 = new ImageIcon(colored2[2]);
    final ImageIcon cell4 = new ImageIcon(colored2[3]);

    compGuess[0].setIcon(cell1);
    compGuess[1].setIcon(cell2);
    compGuess[2].setIcon(cell3);
    compGuess[3].setIcon(cell4);

    //adding a label to tell user where their guessing at
    JLabel user = new JLabel("Your Guess: ");
    user.setForeground(Color.green);
    p2.add(user);

    //adding your guessing buttons
    final JButton[] uG = new JButton[4];
    uG[0] = new JButton();
    uG[1] = new JButton();
    uG[2] = new JButton();
    uG[3] = new JButton();

    p2.add(uG[0]);
    p2.add(uG[1]);
    p2.add(uG[2]);
    p2.add(uG[3]);

    //This is the mouse event handler that make it change colors
    //to the corresponding color that you want with the click of
    //the mouse on the button
    uG[0].addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
    {
        @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getClickCount() == 1)
            {
                uG[0].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-red.png"));
            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 2)
            {
                uG[0].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-blue.png"));
            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 3)
            {
                uG[0].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-green.png"));
            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 4)
            {
                uG[0].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-yellow.png"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    });

    uG[1].addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
    {
        @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getClickCount() == 1)
            {
                uG[1].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-red.png"));
            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 2)
            {
                uG[1].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-blue.png"));
            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 3)
            {
                uG[1].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-green.png"));
            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 4)
            {
                uG[1].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-yellow.png"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    });

    uG[2].addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
    {
        @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getClickCount() == 1)
            {
                uG[2].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-red.png"));
            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 2)
            {
                uG[2].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-blue.png"));
            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 3)
            {
                uG[2].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-green.png"));
            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 4)
            {
                uG[2].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-yellow.png"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    });

    uG[3].addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
    {       
                    @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getClickCount() == 1)
            {
                uG[3].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-red.png"));
            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 2)
            {
                uG[3].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-blue.png"));
            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 3)
            {
                uG[3].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-green.png"));
            }
            else if(e.getClickCount() == 4)
            {
                uG[3].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-yellow.png"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    });

    submit.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
    {

    @Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{   
    if(e.getSource() == submit)
    {
        int s = 0;

        System.out.println(uG[0].getIcon());
        System.out.println(uG[1].getIcon());
        System.out.println(uG[2].getIcon());
        System.out.println(uG[3].getIcon());
        System.out.println(compGuess[0].getIcon());
        System.out.println(compGuess[1].getIcon());
        System.out.println(compGuess[2].getIcon());
        System.out.println(compGuess[3].getIcon());

        if(uG[0].getIcon() == compGuess[0].getIcon() && uG[1].getIcon() == compGuess[1].getIcon() && uG[2].getIcon() == compGuess[2].getIcon() && uG[3].getIcon() == compGuess[3].getIcon())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f1, "You have guessed them all coorect!", "Mastermind: Test Your Mind", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            submit.setEnabled(false);
            compGuess[0].setEnabled(false);
            compGuess[1].setEnabled(false);
            compGuess[2].setEnabled(false);
            compGuess[3].setEnabled(false);
            uG[0].setEnabled(false);
            uG[1].setEnabled(false);
            uG[2].setEnabled(false);
            uG[3].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {   
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f1, "Please try again!", "Mastermind: Test Your Mind", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }


        guesses++;
        tf1.setValue(new Integer(guesses));

        if(guesses == 10)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f1, "Thank you for playing! \n\n\n Have a wonderful day.", "Mastermind: Test Your Mind", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        if(uG[0].getIcon() == compGuess[0].getIcon())
        {
            x = x + 1;
        }
        if(uG[1].getIcon() == compGuess[1].getIcon())
        {
            x = x + 1;
        }
        if(uG[2].getIcon() == compGuess[2].getIcon())
        {
            x = x + 1;
        }
        if(uG[3].getIcon() == compGuess[2].getIcon())
        {
            x = x + 1;
        }

        if(uG[0].getIcon() != compGuess[0].getIcon())
        {
            y = y + 1;
        }
        if(uG[1].getIcon() != compGuess[1].getIcon())
        {
            y = y + 1;
        }
        if(uG[2].getIcon() != compGuess[2].getIcon())
        {
            y = y + 1;
        }
        if(uG[3].getIcon()!= compGuess[2].getIcon())
        {
            y = y + 1;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f1, "You have " + x + " colors correct and in the right position."+
                                                     "\nYou have " + y + " colors correct but in the wrong position.", "Mastermind: Test Your      Mind", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    });
    //set the component of the game on the f1
    //and also sets the size of the fame and makes
    // its visible to the user
    f1.add(Gs, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    f1.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f1.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    f1.setSize(650, 350);
    f1.setVisible(true);
    f1.setResizable(false);
    f1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Mastermind mastermind = new Mastermind();
}   
    }
```

Thanks in advance Jay!

Comment: "You can comment out the audio part to it and change the icon's." That's not the way a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) works. The idea of the SSCCE is actually to provide your helpers with _as small as possible_ code that only shows the problem you have. This way the helper will not have to waste his time reading the whole code but just can read through the small code or even copy paste it to his IDE to reproduce your problem.

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) shows how to make your icons self-contained, and it may suggest a different way to organize your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you describe is caused by comparing distinct references.

The `compGuess` array is initialized by something like (distributed accross your sorce code, but basically it's like that):

```
// colored2[0] contains filename
final ImageIcon cell1 = new ImageIcon(colored2[0]);  
compGuess[0] = new JButton();
compGuess[0].setIcon(cell1);
```

i.e. you create a `JButton` and assign a newly created `ImageIcon` to that button.

On the other hand for `uG` we have the code

```
uG[0] = new JButton();
uG[0].setIcon(new ImageIcon("circle-red.png"));    // inside mouse listener
```

which means you again create a button and assign another instance of `ImageIcon` to that one.

So when you compare

```
uG[0].getIcon() == compGuess[0].getIcon()
```

you actually compare the icon instances which of course never match since they were created independently and are thus always distinct objects.

To fix this issue you may create each distinct icon once and share/reuse it for all your components. But I'd prefer a different way and separate the representation (icons) from the underlying data model and have both stored with a suitable (view-independent) data type (e.g. `enum DiskColor { RED, BLUE, GREEN, YELLOW };`) which you can easily compare but also transform into your view representation.

Comment: Thank you, I declared the icons up top with RED, BLUE, GREEN, and YELLOW. Then set them equal to the corresponding icons, e.g. public ImageIcon RED = new ImageIcon("circle-red.png");. And just set everything that was using the color to RED. And now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Put something like:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.exit(0);
```

On the code that shows the user that the number was guessed correctly. I think the problem is that there are not-daemon threads running on the background and you don't specify that you want the program to end.

Comment: -1 Do not sleep on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).